# Serializing DirectoryServices SearchResult to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am having trouble Serializing a DirectoryServices SearchResult to JSON using Newtonsoft in C#.

I am looking to do something like this:

```
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchResult.Properties);
```

With the expectation of receiving:

```
{
  "cn": "Some User",
  "accountexpires": 0,
  "msexchuseraccountcontrol": 0,
  "badpasswordtime": 131710299813433259,
  "someTrueArray": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Instead I am getting this (which is creating arrays out of string and ints):

```
{
  "cn": ["Some User"],
  "accountexpires": [0],
  "msexchuseraccountcontrol": [0],
  "badpasswordtime": [131710299813433259],
  "someTrueArray": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: It looks like each property returns a [ResultProperCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.resultpropertycollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx) so you might have to do some manual flattening, or write a custom serializer.

Comment: Thank you stuartd, that is what I was trying to avoid :-). But I think you are probably right unfortunately.